# Preserving version comment in the document library

Tags: versioning, office-365, version-comments

I am trying to migrate the document library from Sharepoint 2010 to SharePoint2013 using the Client Object Model.

I have used FPSE for check out and check in. Using these I am able to   preserve the version comment but the number of version increase with every check out and check in. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SharePoint SE. To make your question a little clearer can I ask why you want versioning but don't want version numbers?

Comment: Are you getting 402/404 on other tan current versions of a document>

Comment: I do want the version numbers but when i try to preserve the version comment for a particular version, an extra version is created which i do not want.

Comment: No I am not getting 402/404 but i am getting an extra version each time i try to migrate the version comment.